# pop up dialog box in-font of screen javascript/ jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to pop up dialog box in-front of screen while browser minimized or not used or tap not used

I mean
1) I open http://exampe.com/popup.html where jquery script pop up a dialog box every 5 min asking to click close  button to close it. it is working fine
2) Now I minimize it OR open another tap OR open another browser where I browse another website (www.google.com or any others)
3) I need to popup same dialog box every 5 min in-front of screen

Is it possible?

thanks

Comment: anyone can answer my question?

Comment: no one help me.

Comment: is it stupid question?

Comment: please help me ...